# Monkey patching XMLHttpRequest in a Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I'm building a Safari extension for my personal use, and one of the requisites that I have is to be able to monitor the network requests.

For the purpose of that, I have more than enough with the usual XMLHttpRequest monkey patching. There are quite some examples here, in SO, and quite some libraries in GitHub. I'm using https://github.com/wendux/Ajax-hook and the example code from the README.

I created a new Safari extension (Safari -> Development -> Show extensions creator -> New Extension), created a new empty fiel and copied the minified version of the library and demo code. Then I set the access privileges of the extension to "All", added the .js file that I just created to the "Initial scripts" section and loaded the extension.

I'd expect that the requests of the tabs that I open to trigger the `console.log`s from the demo code, but they are not triggering anything.

If I copy and paste the code from my extension, as-is, in the dev console of Safari and then try to load something via ajax, the `console.log`s start showing. This makes me think that there is some sort of limitation of what a Safari extension can override using prototypes. Or maybe there is some other limitation that I'm not aware of.

What am I missing? Why the XMLHttpRequest prototype overriding is not working?

My code looks like this:

```
if (window.top === window) {
    window.onload = function() {
        // https://github.com/wendux/Ajax-hook
        <-- here goes the minified version of the lib -->

        hookAjax({
            //hook callbacks
            onreadystatechange:function(xhr){
                console.log("onreadystatechange called: %O",xhr)
            },
            onload:function(xhr){
                console.log("onload called: %O",xhr)
            },
            //hook function
            open:function(arg,xhr){
                console.log("open called: method:%s,url:%s,async:%s",arg[0],arg[1],arg[2])
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: are you expecting the extension to "hook into" XHR requests for every web page, or just XHR requests within the extension itself?

Comment: @JaromandaX for every web page.

Comment: I know how you'd do it in firefox/chrome/edge, but not Safari - in the other browsers you'd use [this concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) - are Safari extensions at all like the (standard) Web Extensions?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not sure, but I don't think so.

Comment: well, with web extensions, there are also different "types" of script ... background content, content script etc ... content script is what is "injected" into the page - this is the type of script you would need to use (whatever is equivalent in safari extensions) - I'm not familiar at all with Safari, so I'll bow out now

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I'm using an injected js, so this is the equivalent. And according to the docs it should be working. But it doesn't.

Comment: OK - well at least that's cleared up :p in the console, if you `console.log(window._ahrealxhr)` - what do you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176366/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-jaromanda-x).